# ¿A que se debe el error Estado HTTP 404 - /manager/html en tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servidor

Lo que acabo de realizar es descargar e instalar la version 8.0 de el servidor de tomcat en el entorno de eclipse, pero al momento de iniciar el servidor y tratar de acceder al administrador de tomcat me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy accediendo con la ruta de `localhost:8080`.

Ya hice lo del boton de switch

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sigue sin desabilitarse la seccion de servidores locales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @David, ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo? He leído en un montón de sitios lo del "switch location", cambiar el "Server Locations" a la opción "Use Tomcat installation". He hecho todo eso y me sigue sin funcionar. Tengo un archivo .html y no consigo que cargue. La página de inicio de Tomcat local si me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error 404 indica que estás intentando acceder a un recurso que no existe, en este caso la aplicación manager, y dentro de esta, la ruta /html.
Si compruebas el log de arranque del tomcat podrás verificar qué aplicaciones se están desplegando y así saber si manager está o no en tu instalación de tomcat.